# Why do we set initial condition to rest when solving impulse response

Tags: initial-value-problems

When we are solving for impulse response, I have seen many people use initial conditions at rest ($y(0)=0$ for first order).

What is the meaning behind this?

Thank you.

Comment: this means that at the initial moment of time $t=0$ the value of the function we are looking for is set to zero

Comment: Why we have to do that? Why is it needed to be zero?

Comment: there are not unique solution of differential equation and we should choose one of them for example such solution which y(0)=0. You can choose other solution y(2018)=100500 but it is not more better.

Comment: Let me rephase my question. Initial condition has nothing to deal with impulse response, what is the physical meaning of this? Sorry, if it is ambiguous. I am trying to find more proper words.